# How to align content on a banner if there's a HTML5 video involved

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I may need to re-title this post. I have a HTML5 video but I'm having a very hard time styling it the way I want it to.

**HTML**

```
<header>
        <div class="video-holder full-img">
            <video autoplay loop muted>
                <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/syau.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/syau.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="height:100%">
            <div class="row" style="height:100%">

                <div class="banner-text col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1>Step<br>Your<br><span id="type-selector" class="typed-element"></span><br>Up</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-container col-md-2">
                    <div class="btn-cta">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/roster/">Check us out</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

This is how I'm doing HTML5 video. I have Javascript to get the height of the device so the banner always matches it.

**Javascript**

```
function windowResizeFunctions(e) {

        var windowH = $(window).height(),
            headerH = $('#my-navbar').height();

        $('header').css('height', windowH);

    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(windowResizeFunctions);
    });  

    setTimeout(function() { windowResizeFunctions(); 
    });
```

This is my CSS

```
header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}
.banner-text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.banner-text h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-container {
    z-index: 201;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.btn-cta {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
}

.video-holder {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:200%;
    left:-50%;
}
video {
    position:absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    bottom: -99999px;
    left: -99999px;
    right: -99999px;
    margin: auto;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:50%;
}
```

Now, this is my real live [example](http://www.stepyouraimup.com/). On laptop this looks how I want it, but on everything else it's very hard to work with. What I'm trying to achieve is the banner text on the left, and the button on the bottom right of the container so it's leveled with the baseline of the last word.

I thought to do flexbox. I tried giving `.row` `display:flex` and `.banner-text` `align-items:center;` but that wouldn't work. I tried a variety of HTML changes to move things around and I couldn't get it, I'd post my attempts but this question would become massive.

I just want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzyFP.jpg) on laptop/desktop. On tablet and mobile I just want it to stack, text on top and button below. This is coded terribly and I'm not sure how to properly do it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<a>` button inside the `<h1>` tag -- as the last element.

Increase the width of the `<h1>` tag by changing its parent class from `col-md-6` to `col-md-8`.

Set the following CSS to the button:

```
float:right;
position:relative;
top:40px;
```

It's a little hacky and there's def better solutions out there but that would require restructuring your entire DOM. This is the easiest fix.